# Wireless router a on plane

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items

Can I use a wireless router on a plane to play video games with friends during our flight? I will be using an old linksys router and need to connect a Mac and a pc together.

Comment: Also see *[Are those devices allowed on a flight which create their own WiFi signals?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11991)* at Aviation.SE.

Comment: An ad-hoc wifi network, or a crossover cable would seem easier.

Answer (score 3):

No, you may not.  Here is [United's electronic devices policy](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/devices.aspx), which is entirely standard across the airline industry and just happens to be the first one I found when I searched.  It says,

> **Devices that are NOT permitted for use:**
>
> - radio receivers and transmitters

A WiFi router is a radio transmitter, so it is not allowed.

As another example, [British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/pdfs/handheld-devices-used-onboard_Dec14.pdf) says

> Any device that transmits or receives communications but does not have a ‘flight safe’ mode, must be 
>   switched off for the duration of the flight.

[Japan Airlines](https://www.jal.com/en/flight/safety/flight/phone.html) says,

> Please set electronic devices to the mode which do not emit electronic signals or turn them off when cabin attendants request to do so after all doors are closed. Those who break the law may be subject to fine of up to 500,000 yen.

and has a diagram showing that "electronic devices that intentionally emit radio waves when activated" must be switched off between the time when the cabin door closes and after landing. "Mobile routers" are explicitly listed as forbidden at this time.

Comment: A laptop with wifi is also a radio transmitter, but United permits in-flight wifi.

Comment: Correct, they all have Wifi nowadays. Supposedly their wifi sources are verified against negative side effects, but even then - your mobile phone is talking back to the wifi router, so it is sending anyway. It is just a historic rule, and nobody wants to take the responsibility for declaring it unnecessary.

Comment: Laptops, tablets, phone all have transmit capability when used for wifi, but they are not on the prohibited list.  Rules do not always make sense.  You are of course welcome to argue the case with lawmakers, but that would likely result with ALL wifi being banned ;-)

Comment: Could you just use one of the laptops to create an ad-hoc network?

Comment: There is a software called "connectify" which you could use to create a wifi network using a laptop.